# Cannot find alternative to sendmail on Windows

Tags: php, postfix, sendmail, xampp

On Windows, I used XAMPP, PHP, and Sendmail to be able to send an email from a specific gmail account to another.

LAMPP on Linux does not come with Sendmail, so I tried installing it and linking it, but I encountered a small problem. On Windows, I placed my SMTP settings with the account email and the password in an existing sendmail.ini. However the sendmail on Linux does not come with an .ini, and I can't find whether I can use an .ini or where to place it anywhere.

I also tried Postfix, using the steps from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47609/how-to-have-my-php-send-mail), but `/etc/postfix/sender_canonical` does not exist, and I tried reinstalling up to three times with no effect.

Is there a way I can use LAMPP and PHP to send mail to a gmail account using Sendmail, or do I need to use something completely different?